# data from core data in picker view

Tags: ios, core-data, swift3, uipickerview

i work on an app for a school project. The app should manage different customers(with the name from the customer and the email address) and tasks(with the name of the task and the price per hour). 
then the app should create a bill from this data.

My problem is how can i get the data from the customers and tasks(stored in Core Data) in two picker views?

Link to the complete Project: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bwwqhrg9CBVfTU50R2dBaF9ZcUk

(Sorry for using German variables and function names :/ )

this is the Resource for the tasks

```
//
//  ArrayAufgabenResource.swift
//  TheServiceAppV2
//
//  Created by David Zerweck on 09.04.17.
//  Copyright © 2017 David Zerweck. All rights reserved.
//

////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //German = English

    //Kunde = Customer
    //Aufgabe = Task
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
import Foundation
import CoreData

struct ArrayAufgabeResource: AufgabeResource {

var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {

    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "TheServiceAppV2")
    container.loadPersistentStores {
        (storeDescription, error) in

        if let error = error {
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Fehler: \(nserror.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
    return container
}()

func saveContext() {
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    if context.hasChanges {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Fehler: \(nserror.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}

func insertAufgabe(withName: String, andPreis: String) -> Aufgabe {
    let newAufgabe = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Aufgabe", into: persistentContainer.viewContext) as! Aufgabe

    newAufgabe.nameDerAufgabe = withName
    newAufgabe.preisProStunde = andPreis

    saveContext()
    return newAufgabe
}

func remove(aufgabe: Aufgabe) {
    persistentContainer.viewContext.delete(aufgabe)
    saveContext()
}

func getList() -> [Aufgabe] {
    var aufgaben = [Aufgabe]()

    let request: NSFetchRequest<Aufgabe> = Aufgabe.fetchRequest()
    do {
        aufgaben = try persistentContainer.viewContext.fetch(request)
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    return aufgaben
}   
}
```

this is the Customer Resource

```
//
//  ArrayKundenResource.swift
//  TheServiceAppV2
//
//  Created by David Zerweck on 09.04.17.
//  Copyright © 2017 David Zerweck. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation
import CoreData

struct ArrayKundeResource: KundeResource {

var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {

    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "TheServiceAppV2")
    container.loadPersistentStores {
        (storeDescription, error) in

        if let error = error {
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Fehler: \(nserror.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

    return container
}()

func saveContext() {
    let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
    if context.hasChanges {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            let nserror = error as NSError
            fatalError("Fehler: \(nserror.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}

func insertKunde(withName: String, andEmail: String) -> Kunde {

    let newKunde = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Kunde", into: persistentContainer.viewContext) as! Kunde

    newKunde.name = withName
    newKunde.email = andEmail

    saveContext()

    return newKunde
}

func remove(kunde: Kunde) {
    persistentContainer.viewContext.delete(kunde)
    saveContext()
}


func getList() -> [Kunde] {
    var kunden = [Kunde]()

    let request: NSFetchRequest<Kunde> = Kunde.fetchRequest()
    do {
        kunden = try persistentContainer.viewContext.fetch(request)
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    return kunden
 }
}
```

In the following ViewController, there should be two picker views. The first picker view should show the customers. and the second picker view should show the tasks.

```
//
//  RechnungViewController.swift
//  TheServiceAppV2
//
//  Created by David Zerweck on 17.05.17.
//  Copyright © 2017 David Zerweck. All rights reserved.
//

////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//German = English

//Kunde = Customer
//Aufgabe = Task
//Rechnung = Bill
////////////////////////////////////////////////////

import UIKit

class RechnungViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var pickerViewKunde: UIPickerView!

@IBOutlet weak var pickerViewAufgabe: UIPickerView!

@IBOutlet weak var anzahlStundenField: UITextField! //number of hours


@IBAction func rechnungBtn(_ sender: Any) {
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
 }
}
```

i hope somebody can help me.
I'm already saying thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can get data like below code:

Here is your controller, Please simply copy paste and get it work.

```
import UIKit

class RechnungViewController: UIViewController , UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {


@IBOutlet weak var pickerViewKunde: UIPickerView!

@IBOutlet weak var pickerViewAufgabe: UIPickerView!

@IBOutlet weak var anzahlStundenField: UITextField!


var allKunden = [Kunde]()

@IBAction func rechnungBtn(_ sender: Any) {
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //Temp Add data
    var kun = Kunde()
    let arr : ArrayKundeResource = ArrayKundeResource()
    kun = arr.insertKunde(withName: "JIGAR", andEmail: "jigar@mail.com")
    print(kun.email)
    print(kun.name)
 //This is for temporary adding data inside coredata so you can remove this.

    //get all customer
    self.getAllCustomer()
}

func getAllCustomer() {

    let arr : ArrayKundeResource = ArrayKundeResource()
    self.allKunden = arr.getList()

    print(self.allKunden.count)
}

//pickerview datasource methods
func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return self.allKunden.count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    let kundObj = self.allKunden[row] as Kunde
    return kundObj.name
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    let kundObj = self.allKunden[row] as Kunde
    print(kundObj.name)
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

}
```